# Python Selenium on IE not able to locate elements?

Tags: python, selenium

So im having some trouble locating the following element 
`<input type="text" class="black_ar" maxlength="255" size="10" name="mrn">`. I have tried to locate it using xpath but it says that it "list object has not attribute send_keys" and using driver.find_element_by_class_name('black_ar') gives the error "Unable to find element with css selector == .black_ar". I have no idea what to do :( please help

Gives error: Unable to find element with css selector == .black_ar

```
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    mrnbox = driver.find_element_by_class_name('black_ar').send_keys(mrn)
    print(mrn)
```

Gives error: Unable to find element with css selector == [name="mrn"]

```
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    mrnbox = driver.find_element_by_name('mrn').send_keys(mrn)
    print(mrn)
```

Gives error: Unable to find element with xpath

```
 driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    mrnbox = 
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/a[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[3]/td[2]/span[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[2]/input[1]').send_keys(mrn)
    print(mrn)
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: I need to see code to really diagnose, but one potential problem might be a difference between the page source HTML and the html in "inspect element" after the javascript runs. If i remember correctly you can have selenium run on the HTML before or after javascript

Comment: @Rorschach ok i updated the post to include the code

Comment: Is the element inside an IFRAME? Please edit your code down to a [mcve] so we don't have to narrow down the code ourselves to the actual issue.

Comment: @JeffC ok sorry about that, i think it should be fixed now. And no from what i can tell it is not an iframe, i also used ChroPath which is a chrome extension to get the text box xpath if that helps.

Comment: Go into the dev console on Chrome and run `$$(".black_ar")`. How many elements does it return?

Comment: @JeffC it returns 46 elements

Comment: So that means that the locator is good but you've either got a timing issue or the elements are in an IFRAME. If it's a timing issue, you will need to add a wait. You probably should look again and make sure the elements are not in an IFRAME. Can you post a link to the page?

Comment: @JeffC i wouldnt be able to since the site is locked to our network and cannot be accessed anywhere else. If it were to be in an IFRAME what would i have to do?

Comment: You would need to find the name of the IFRAME that contains the elements you are looking for and then switch the driver context to that IFRAME, interact with the elements, switch back to default context, etc. If you google "python selenium switch iframe" you should find a bunch of info on how to deal with elements in IFRAMEs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to send a *character sequence* to the desired element you can use either of the following solutions:

- `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.black_ar[name='mrn']").send_keys("Collette jorike")
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='black_ar' and @name='mrn']").send_keys("Collette jorike")
  ```

---

### Update

As you are seeing the error as *"Unable to find element with ..." error* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `css_selector`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.black_ar[name='mrn']"))).send_keys("Collette jorike")
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='black_ar' and @name='mrn']"))).send_keys("Collette jorike")
  ```

Comment: Ok i tried both but it still gives me the same " Unable to find element with ..." error. I tried both with and without a pause of 5 seconds

Comment: Try like five minutes of waiting @Collettejorike your selenium browser could be loading the page really slow and you are parsing an unfinished page.

Comment: @Collettejorike Checkout my answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: @Collettejorike Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.